# Using Join, Group By, and Sum in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

My models look like:

```
public class ReturnItem
{
    public int returnItemId { get ; set; }
    public int returnRequestId { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnRequest
{
    public int returnRequestId { get; set; }
    public string orderNumber  { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReturnItem> returnItems { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT item, sum(quantity)
FROM ReturnItem
JOIN ReturnRequest
ON ReturnRequest.returnRequestId = ReturnItem.returnRequestId
WHERE ReturnRequest.orderNumber = '1XX'
GROUP BY item
```

How do I convert the query to Entity Framework and return a `List<ReturnItem>`? Can I use `.Include` instead of `.Join`?

Answer (score 7):

```
from ri in db.ReturnItems
join rr in db.ReturnRequests
   on ri.returnRequestId equals rr.returnRequestId
where rr.orderNumber == "1XX"
group ri by ri.item into g
select new {
   Item = g.Key,
   Quantity = g.Sum(i => i.quantity)
}
```

You can't use `Include` instead of `Join` because `Include` translated into *Left Outer Join* but you need *Inner Join* here.

But you can use navigation property to perform join implicitly:

```
db.ReturnRequests
  .Where(rr => rr.orderNumber == "1XX")
  .SelectMany(rr => rr.returnItems)
  .GroupBy(ri => ri.item)
  .Select(g => new {
      Item = g.Key,
      Quantity = g.Sum(ri => ri.quantity)
  });
```

Comment: How do I return a `List<ReturnItem>` from this query?

Comment: @janinaj your SQL query returned different result. But you can select `new ReturnItem { item = g.Key, quantity = g.Sum(i => i.quantity)}` instead of anonymous object. Converting to list is pretty easy I think

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error `The specified type member 'returnItems' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: @janinaj unfortunately it's not possible to construct complex type in entity query. So you need to load anonymous objects from database and then with `AsEnumerable()` call and then project anonymous objects to `ReturnItem` type